# Why does the Tensorflow JS model not learn?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have build a model with tfjs based on the [IRIS Classification example](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-examples/iris/dist/index.html). After I removed the third label the AI doesn't work anymore and it's Loss and Accuracy lock at 4.6 and 0.5. Also the prediction after training are after the removing of the third label wrong. I think, that maybe the Loss function, the optimizer or the metrics are wrong for this type of AI.

Any Suggestions, what could be wrong with this model?

Code Information:

Data example: [24, 10, 20, 10, 1] 
(The first four numbers stand for an Outfit and the last digit stand for the rating)

Label before removing: [0 = bad rating, 1 = good rating, 2 = no opinion]

Label after removing: [0 = bad rating, 1 = good rating]

Optimizer: RMSProp

Loss function: categoricalCrossentropy

Metrics: accuracy

Learning Rate: 0.1

Epochs: 100

The Outfit is changed to a oneHot encoding

InputShape: [null, 4, 27]

OutputShape: [null, 2]

Modell Summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,4,10]               280       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_Flatten1 (Flatten)   [null,40]                 0         
 _________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense2 (Dense)         [null,2]                  82        
=================================================================
Total params: 362
Trainable params: 362
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My Code after removing

```
const stringdata = document.getElementById('stringdata').innerHTML;
console.log(string(stringdata));
const IRIS_DATA = string(stringdata);
const kleidungo = document.getElementById('kleidungo').innerHTML;
const kleidungu = document.getElementById('kleidungu').innerHTML;
const Kleidung = [string(kleidungo), string(kleidungu)];
console.log(Kleidung);

import { string } from './js.js';
import * as tfVis from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis';

async function ki() {
    const IRIS_CLASSES = ['Bad', 'Good'];
    const IRIS_NUM_CLASSES = IRIS_CLASSES.length;

    var epochsnum = 0;
    console.log(tfVis); // [object Module] { ... }

    function doPrediction(model, xTest, yTest) {
        const labels = yTest.argMax([-1]);
        const preds = model.predict(xTest).argMax([-1]);
        xTest.dispose();
        return [preds, labels];
    }
    async function calculateAndDrawConfusionMatrix(model, xTest, yTest) {
        const [preds, labels] = doPrediction(model, xTest, yTest);
        const confusionMatrix = await tfvis.metrics.confusionMatrix(labels, preds);
        const container = document.getElementById('confusion-matrix');
        tfvis.render.confusionMatrix(container, {
            values: confusionMatrix,
            tickLabels: IRIS_CLASSES
        });
        labels.dispose();
    }
    function convertToTensors(data, targets, testSplit) {
        const numExamples = data.length;
        if (numExamples !== targets.length) {
            throw new Error('data and split have different numbers of examples');
        }

        // Randomly shuffle `data` and `targets`.
        const indices = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numExamples; ++i) {
            indices.push(i);
        }
        tf.util.shuffle(indices);

        const shuffledData = [];
        const shuffledTargets = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numExamples; ++i) {
            shuffledData.push(data[indices[i]]);
            shuffledTargets.push(targets[indices[i]]);
        }

        // Split the data into a training set and a tet set, based on `testSplit`.
        const numTestExamples = Math.round(numExamples * testSplit);
        const numTrainExamples = numExamples - numTestExamples;
        
        const xDims = shuffledData[0].length;

        // Create a `tf.Tensor` to hold the feature data.
        //var dataByClass = tf.oneHot(dataByClass2, 27);
        const xs = tf.oneHot(shuffledData, 27);

        // Create a 1D `tf.Tensor` to hold the labels, and convert the number label
        // from the set {0, 1, 2} into one-hot encoding (.e.g., 0 --> [1, 0, 0]).
        const ys = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(shuffledTargets).toInt(), IRIS_NUM_CLASSES);

        // Split the data into training and test sets, using `slice`.
        const xTrain = xs.slice([0, 0], [numTrainExamples, xDims]);
        const xTest = xs.slice([numTrainExamples, 0], [numTestExamples, xDims]);
        const yTrain = ys.slice([0, 0], [numTrainExamples, IRIS_NUM_CLASSES]);
        const yTest = ys.slice([0, 0], [numTestExamples, IRIS_NUM_CLASSES]);
        return [xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest];
    }


    function getIrisData(testSplit) {
        return tf.tidy(() => {
            const dataByClass = [];
            const targetsByClass = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < IRIS_CLASSES.length; ++i) {
                dataByClass.push([]);
                targetsByClass.push([]);
            }
            for (const example of IRIS_DATA) {
                const target = example[example.length - 1];
                const data = example.slice(0, example.length - 1);
                dataByClass[target].push(data);
                targetsByClass[target].push(target);
            }

            const xTrains = [];
            const yTrains = [];
            const xTests = [];
            const yTests = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < IRIS_CLASSES.length; ++i) {
            const [xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest] =
                convertToTensors(dataByClass[i], targetsByClass[i], testSplit);
                xTrains.push(xTrain);
                yTrains.push(yTrain);
                xTests.push(xTest);
                yTests.push(yTest);
            }
            const concatAxis = 0;
            return [
                tf.concat(xTrains, concatAxis), tf.concat(yTrains, concatAxis),
                tf.concat(xTests, concatAxis), tf.concat(yTests, concatAxis)
            ];
        });
    }

    function loadTrainParametersFromUI() {
        return {
            epochs: 100,
            learningRate: 0.1
        };
    }
    async function trainModel(xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest) {
        document.getElementById('Epochs').innerHTML = 'Model is create...';
        const params = loadTrainParametersFromUI();
        
        console.log('Shape: ' + xTrain.shape + '\n Data:')
        xTrain.print();
        console.log('Shape: ' + yTrain.shape + '\n Data:')
        yTrain.print();

        
        // Define the topology of the model: two dense layers.
        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense(
            {
                units: 10, 
                activation: 'sigmoid', 
                inputShape: [
                    xTrain.shape[1], 
                    xTrain.shape[2]
                ]
            }
        ));
        model.add(
            tf.layers.flatten()
        );
        model.add(tf.layers.dense(
            {
                units: 2, 
                activation: 'softmax'
            }
        ));
        model.summary();

        const opti = "rmsprop";
        const optimizer = tf.train.rmsprop(params.learningRate);
        model.compile(
            {
                optimizer: optimizer,
                loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
                metrics: ['accuracy'],
            }
        );
    
        const trainLogs = [];
        const lossContainer = document.getElementById('lossCanvas');
        const accContainer = document.getElementById('accuracyCanvas');
        const beginMs = performance.now();
        console.log('epochs: ' + params.epochs + ', lr: ' + params.learningRate + ', opti: ' + opti);
        // Call `model.fit` to train the model.
        const surface = { 
            name: 'show.fitCallbacks', 
            tab: 'Training' 
        };

        //Train with callback after each epoh -> Diagramm
        const history = await model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, {
            epochs: params.epochs,
            validationData: [xTest, yTest],
            callbacks: {
                onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
                    // Plot the loss and accuracy values at the end of every training epoch.
                    const secPerEpoch = (performance.now() - beginMs) / (1000 * (epoch + 1));
                    trainLogs.push(logs); 
                    epochsnum++;
                    document.getElementById('Epochs').innerHTML = (
                        'Epoche ' + epochsnum + "/" + params.epochs + '<br>Dauer der letzten Epoche: '+ secPerEpoch.toFixed(5) + 's <br> Verstrichene Zeit: ' + ((performance.now() - beginMs) / 1000).toFixed(5) + 's'
                        );
                    document.getElementById('Progressbar').innerHTML = (
                        '<progress id="progress" value="' + epochsnum + '" max="' + params.epochs + '"> ' + epochsnum + '% </progress>'
                        );
                    console.log(epochsnum + '. Epoche');
                    console.log('Epochendauer der Epoche ' + epochsnum + ': ' + secPerEpoch.toFixed(5));
                    console.log('Loss ', trainLogs[epochsnum-1].loss.toFixed(5));
                    console.log('Accuracy ', trainLogs[epochsnum-1].acc.toFixed(5));
                    tfvis.show.history(
                        lossContainer, 
                        trainLogs, 
                        ['loss']
                    );
                    tfvis.show.history(
                        accContainer, 
                        trainLogs, 
                        ['acc']
                    );
                },
            },
        
        });

        //Data Output
        async function calculateAndDrawConfusionMatrix(model, xTest, yTest) {
            const [preds, labels] = tf.tidy(() => {
                const preds = model.predict(xTest).argMax(-1);
                const labels = yTest.argMax(-1);
                return [preds, labels];
            });
            
            const confMatrixData = await tfvis.metrics.confusionMatrix(labels, preds);
            const container = document.getElementById('confusion-matrix');
            tfvis.render.confusionMatrix(
                container, 
                {
                    values: confMatrixData, 
                    labels: IRIS_CLASSES
                },
                {
                    shadeDiagonal: true
                },
            );
            
            tf.dispose([
                preds, 
                labels
            ]);
        }
        calculateAndDrawConfusionMatrix(model, xTest, yTest);
        const secPerEpoch = (performance.now() - beginMs) / (1000 * params.epochs);
        console.log((performance.now() - beginMs) / 1000);
        console.log(secPerEpoch);
        document.getElementById('Epochs').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('Progressbar').innerHTML = '';
        var time = ((performance.now() - beginMs) / 1000).toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById('secperEpochs').innerHTML = (
            'Durchschnittliche Dauer einer Epoche: ' + secPerEpoch.toFixed(5) + ' Sekunden <br> Gesamte Dauer: ' + time + 's'
            );

        //Predict Test
        console.log('predict [2, 2, 14, 1]' + model.predict(
            tf.oneHot(
                [[2, 2, 14, 1]], 
                27
            )
        ));
        var predict = model.predict(
            tf.oneHot(
                [[2, 2, 14, 1]], 
                27
            )
        );
        document.getElementById('Predict').innerHTML = predict;

        console.log("===================================");
        console.log('xTest ' + xTest);
        console.log('Predict ' + model.predict(xTest));
        console.log("===================================");

        function TensortoArray(id) {
            var predictneu = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
            var predict2 = predictneu.replace("Tensor", "");
            predict2 = predict2.split(",");
            var predict2neu = predict2.pop();
            var predict21 = predict2[0];
            predict21 = predict21.replace("[", "");
            predict21 = predict21.replace("[", "");
            predict21 = predict21.replace("\n", "");
            var predict2neu = predict2.shift();
            var predict2neu = predict2.unshift(predict21);
            var arraytensor = [];
            predict2.forEach(element => {
                var inserrrt = parseFloat(element);
                arraytensor.push(inserrrt);
            });
            console.log('ArrayTensor ' + arraytensor);
            var arrayten = [];
            arraytensor.forEach(element => {
                var a1 = arrayten.push(element.toFixed(5)*100); 
            });
            return arrayten;
        }
        var arraytensor = TensortoArray('Predict');
        if (arraytensor[0]>arraytensor[1]) {
            console.log(IRIS_CLASSES[0])
            document.getElementById('Predict').innerHTML = (
                'The Testoutfit is rated ' + IRIS_CLASSES[0] + '. (It is to ' + arraytensor[0] + 'sure)'
                );
        } else {
            console.log(IRIS_CLASSES[1])
            document.getElementById('Predict').innerHTML = (
                'The Testoutfit is rated ' + IRIS_CLASSES[1] + ' . (It is to  ' + arraytensor[1] + 'sure)'
                );
        }

        //Find new good Outfit
        var wert = 0
        var min = 1;
        function random (max) {
            var x = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
            return x;
        }
        var rundenwert = 1;
        while (wert!=1) {
            //Create new random Outfit
            var x1 = random(Kleidung[0].length-1);
            var y1 = random(Kleidung[1].length-1);
            var x2 = random(Kleidung[0].length-1);
            var y2 = random(Kleidung[1].length-1); 
            var array = [];
            var array2 = [];
            var array_x1 = array.push(Kleidung[0][x1][0]);
            var array_y1 = array.push(Kleidung[1][y1][0]);
            var array_x2 = array.push(Kleidung[0][x2][0]);
            var array_y2 = array.push(Kleidung[1][y2][0]);
            var druck = array[0] + ', ' + array[1] + ', ' + array[2] + ', ' + array[3];
            array.forEach(element => {
                array2.push(parseFloat(element));
            });
            console.log('Runde ' + rundenwert);
            document.getElementById("Array Outfit").innerHTML = 'Finales Outfit Array: ' + druck;
            document.getElementById("1o").innerHTML = '1. Top -' + Kleidung[0][x1][1];
            document.getElementById("1u").innerHTML = '1. Lower part -' + Kleidung[1][y1][1];
            document.getElementById("2o").innerHTML = '2. Top -' + Kleidung[0][x2][1];
            document.getElementById("2u").innerHTML = '2. Lower part -' + Kleidung[1][y2][1];
            console.log(druck);
            console.log(array2);    
            
            //Rate the generated Outfit
            console.log(model.predict(tf.oneHot([array2], 27)));
            document.getElementById('Predict Outfit').innerHTML = model.predict(tf.oneHot([array2], 27));
            var predicttensor = TensortoArray('Predict Outfit');
            if (predicttensor[0]>predicttensor[1]) {
                console.log(IRIS_CLASSES[0])
                document.getElementById('Predict Outfit').innerHTML = 'The final outfit is rated ' + IRIS_CLASSES[0] + '. (It is to ' + predicttensor[0] + 'sure)';
            } else if (predicttensor[1]>60) {
                console.log(IRIS_CLASSES[1])
                document.getElementById('Predict Outfit').innerHTML = 'The final outfit is rated ' + IRIS_CLASSES[1] + ' bewertet. (It is to ' + predicttensor[1] + 'sure)';
                wert = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById('Sicherheit Predict').innerHTML = '<progress id="progress" value="' + predicttensor[0] + '" max="100"></progress><label> Schlecht: ' + predicttensor[0] + '%</label><br><progress id="progress" value="' + predicttensor[1] + '" max="100"></progress><label> Gut: ' + predicttensor[1] + '%</label>';
            rundenwert++;
            document.getElementById('Rundenzahl').innerHTML = 'It was ' + rundenwert + ' Rounds used to find a good outfit.';
            
            //If no Outfit is find -> stop 
            if (rundenwert>500) {
                document.getElementById("Rundenzahl").innerHTML = 'That took to long. <br> No good Outfit was found.';
                wert = 1;
            }
        } 

        //Predict Test2
        console.log('test2 ' + model.predict(tf.oneHot([[1,4,3,10]], 27)));
        console.log('test ' + model.predict(tf.oneHot([[3,4,8,13]], 27)));

        //Model Save
        await model.save('http:...')

        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing one of the outputs makes the problem much easier; as such, perhaps you should reduce your learning rate to something like 0.01 or 0.001 so it doesn't overshoot an easier solution.